# Cannot Build App for Device in XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

A few weeks ago I was able to build and test my app on devices just fine using Xcode.  Now when I plug in my iOS 9.1 devices XCode is showing "Device Unavailable".  iOS 8.x devices still build fine.

I think I know the problem.  But I don't know how to fix it.

Xcode was updated to version 7.1 a few days ago.  Well sort of.  When I launch XCode it says I have version 7.0.1.  But when I go to the app store it says I already have the latest version 7.1.  So it won't let me update.  About the only thing I've tried is rebooting my laptop.  What else should I do?

Comment: R u launching the app with correct version? because if you install multiple versions of Xcode to your machine then it may not update the latest version of Xcode as the default version.

Comment: No, I don't think I am launching it with the correct version.  Because "About" says I am using 7.0.1.  But I want to be using 7.1.  I'm just not sure how to launch that version.  (I didn't realize I might have two versions of XCode on the laptop)

Comment: quit your xcode and then right-click on your project file, a pop-up will come with all available versions of xcode on your machine. There you can select the latest version.

Comment: Hmmm.  Well that seems reasonable but when I right click my only choice is XCode 7.0.1.  Once again, I just want to make sure everyone knows that my only choice in the App Store is "Open".  I cannot update.  And my history says I upgraded to 7.1 on Oct. 24th.  But I do not see evidence of a new version being run.

Comment: i'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: Well I fixed it.  What worked was uninstalling XCode (by moving to Trash).  Rebooting.  Then going back to the app store and installing again.  (At 4.3 GB it takes a while.  But this time it worked)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how long did the download take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete xcode app then download it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading Xcode 7.1 directly from the Apple Developer website at:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/